# How to load Pannellum 360 panorama fullscreen on click

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment I have 2 elements on my page. a panorama div and a button. The div only should get initialized on click. I have that part working, but my question is how do I get the viewer to fullscreen on launch.

Show Panorama

.js code

```
vm.openPanorama360 = function () {
    vm.viewer = window.pannellum.viewer('panorama', {
        "type": "equirectangular",
        "panorama": "https://pannellum.org/images/alma.jpg",
        "autoLoad": true
    });

}
```

What I tried,

adding toggle fullscreen function to vm.openPanorama360

```
vm.openPanorama360 = function () {
    vm.viewer = window.pannellum.viewer('panorama', {
        "type": "equirectangular",
        "panorama": "https://pannellum.org/images/alma.jpg",
        "autoLoad": true
    });

    vm.viewer.toggleFullscreen();
}

vm.toggle360FullScreen = function () {
    vm.viewer.toggleFullscreen();
}
```

I've also added a button to toggle full screen and it works as intended.

```
<button ng-click="vm.toggle360FullScreen()">
    Full Screen
</button>
```

May I ask, how do I immediately load fullscreen for pannellum 360 viewer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the author on his git ([link](https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum/issues/824)):

```
vm.viewer.on('load', function () {
  vm.viewer.toggleFullscreen();
});
```

should do the job, as long as `"autoLoad": true` is not present...

I myself can't seen to get on() to register as a function though, as I keep getting:
`vm.viewer.on is not a function`

------ Update ------

So digging around a little more I managed it, by changing the CSS to:

```
<style>
  html {
    height: 100%
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    cursor: default;
  }
  #panorama {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

This also allows you to use `` `autoLoad`: true ``

Answer obtained from [here](https://github.com/mpetroff/pannellum/issues/731).